# How to navigate user to another View Controller in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I would like to navigate the user to next page "StuMenuViewController.cs" right after a valid user credential was key in. May I know how to do that? Or may I know is there any other suggested way to validate user credential before allowing them to access the menu page?

** I am using the storyboard to create a view controller.

Here are my code:

```
public partial class StudentLoginPage : UIViewController
{

    public StudentLoginPage (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {


        base.ViewDidLoad();

    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
    }

    partial void StuLoginBtn_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {

        if (isValidUserName() && isValidPassword())
        {
            new UIAlertView("Succesful Login", null, null, "OK", null).Show();
            StuMenuViewController menuView = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("StuMenuViewController") as StuMenuViewController;
            NavigationController.PushViewController(menuView, true);

        }
        else
        {
            new UIAlertView("Alert", "Invalid Username or Password", null, "OK", null).Show();
        }
    }

    private bool isValidUserName()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(StuUsernameLoginTxt.Text.Trim());
    }

    private bool isValidPassword()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(StuUserpasswordTxt.Text.Trim());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You are probably looking for the Storyboard documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/storyboards/?tabs=vsmac

Comment: Hi Cheesebaron, I was referred to the same link given by you , but when i click the button in the simulator, it pops out the error of "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to instance of the object" at "NavigationController.PushViewController(menuView, true);" section.

Comment: Then something is probably null and you should look into that. It is probably your menuView. Use the debugger to figure out.

Comment: grammatical and other minor corrections for better understanding

Comment: Thank you so much Cheesebaron! I'm finally make it works!